# Finding the average of a column that meets criteria of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and I need to use Python and Pandas to find the average prices of specific items in a column that meet specific criteria. The criteria are "Honda" and "Toyota" in the "manufacturer" column, "good" in the "condition" column, and "sedan" in the "type" column. The prices are in the "price" column

I know I need to use groupby() but i'm not sure what else to do

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("vehicles.csv")
def get_avg_prices():
df.groupby(['criteria','manufacturer','condition']).['price'].mean
```

This is how I started but not sure where to go from here or if this is right

Comment: Well, provide a clear example of the data and your best try to code the logic, then we can help you

Comment: you group on ,manufacturer, condition and type, then take mean for price.   Refer to the guidelines here for providing a minimum reproducible example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added some code that I started out with if that helps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.